# How could I add a list of previous outputs?

Tags: javascript

I have a computer science project and I need to add a list to my program (which is just a simple converter) I want to make a list that stores the previous conversions and then displays them when a button is pressed. I'm still new to programing and my teacher is basically no help since she is a chemistry teacher filling in for the regular cps teacher so if anyone could at least point me in the right direction on how to make a list like that would be much appreciated.

Here is the code :

```
var numInput;
var dropdownInput;
var convertedValue;
var roundedValue;


onEvent("gConversionButton", "click", function( ) {
  numInput = getNumber("numInput");
  dropdownInput = getText("dropdownInput");
  gConversions(numInput, dropdownInput);
});

onEvent("kgConversionButton", "click", function( ) {
  numInput = getNumber("numInput");
  dropdownInput = getText("dropdownInput");
  kgConversions(numInput, dropdownInput);
});

onEvent("tonneConversionButton", "click", function( ) {
  numInput = getNumber("numInput");
  dropdownInput = getText("dropdownInput");
  tonneConversions(numInput, dropdownInput);
});


function tonneConversions() {
  if (dropdownInput == "Ounces") {
    convertOzToTonne();
  } else if ((dropdownInput == "Pounds")) {
    convertLbToTonne();
  } else if ((dropdownInput == "Tons")) {
    convertTToTonne();
  }
}

function convertOzToTonne() {
  convertedValue = numInput / 35274;
  roundedValue = Math.round(convertedValue * 100000) / 100000;
  setText("convertedOutput", roundedValue + "   Tonnes");
}

function convertLbToTonne() {
  convertedValue = numInput / 2205;
  roundedValue = Math.round(convertedValue * 10000) / 10000;
  setText("convertedOutput", roundedValue+ "   Tonnes");
}

function convertTToTonne() {
  convertedValue = numInput * 0.90718474;
  roundedValue = Math.round(convertedValue * 100) / 100;
  setText("convertedOutput", roundedValue+ "   Tonnes");
}

function kgConversions() {
  if (dropdownInput == "Ounces") {
    convertOzToKg();
  } else if ((dropdownInput == "Pounds")) {
    convertLbToKg();
  } else if ((dropdownInput == "Tons")) {
    convertTToKg();
  }
}

function convertOzToKg() {
  convertedValue = numInput / 35.274;
  roundedValue = Math.round(convertedValue * 100) / 100;
  setText("convertedOutput", roundedValue+ "   Kilograms");
}

function convertLbToKg() {
  convertedValue = numInput / 2.205;
  roundedValue = Math.round(convertedValue * 100) / 100;
  setText("convertedOutput", roundedValue+ "   Kilograms");
}

function convertTToKg() {
  convertedValue = Math.round(numInput * 907);
  setText("convertedOutput", convertedValue+ "   Kilograms");
}

function gConversions() {
  if (dropdownInput == "Ounces") {
    convertOzToG();
  } else if ((dropdownInput == "Pounds")) {
    convertLbToG();
  } else if ((dropdownInput == "Tons")) {
    convertTToG();
  }
}


function convertOzToG() {
   convertedValue = Math.round(numInput * 28.35);
  setText("convertedOutput", convertedValue+ "   Grams");
}

function convertLbToG() {
  convertedValue = Math.round(numInput * 454);
  setText("convertedOutput", convertedValue+ "   Grams");
}

function convertTToG() {
  convertedValue = numInput * 907185;
  setText("convertedOutput", convertedValue+ "   Grams");
}
```

Comment: Only include the code relevant to show the issue/problem.

Comment: In any case, starting with an Array would be a start — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array This array might even be of objects with multiple related values for each conversion, eg. `{conversion: "C to F", input: "12C", output: "56F"}`

Comment: Alternatively, simply write these conversion results directly to the DOM (eg. append a table row or list item) and use CSS to hide/display the container.